Clerk Auth handle forceRedirectUrl to userId route
Does anyone have any nice ideas how to handle redirects using a social providers with Clerk and Nextjs14? I want to do something like this for example where the user is redirected to the /user/userId after successful sign-in/sign-up.
I was experimenting with useClerk() hook but it just ended upp in a overcomplicated mess.
export function SignInButton() {
    const { userId } = useAuth();

    return (
        <Button asChild>
            <SignInButton forceRedirectUrl={`/user/${userId}`} mode="modal" />
        </Button>
    );
}


